# Linear Algebra Done Right (2nd edition): what's the meaning of the notation $\overline{q}(x)$ in equation 6.2?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, inner-products

Linear Algebra Done Right: what's the meaning of the notation $\overline{q}(x)$  in equation 6.2: $\langle q,p\rangle=\int_{0}^1p(x)\overline{q}(x)\,dx$, where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are both polynomials of complex coefficients with degree at most $m$? If $q(x)=(a_1+b_1i)x+...+(a_m+b_mi)x^m$, does $\overline{q}(x)=(a_1-b_1i)x+...+(a_m-b_mi)x^m$?

Comment: Yes, $\bar q(x)$ would replace the coefficients in $q$ with the complex conjugates.

Comment: @DougM Thank you very much!